# How to Get translateBinary to Work in Rational Application Developer Data Connection

Tags: db2, websphere-8, ibm-rad

Using Rational Application Developer for Websphere 9.1.0 to make a data connection to a DB2 iseries file, the column data displays a Hex(I think).

I have added the "translateBinary=true" property to the url connection but is does not change the display results.

jdbc:as400:host;translateBinary=true

Comment: All columns or just one?  If the latter, what's the data type of the affected column?

Comment: Several columns but not all. Looking at it closer I do not think the connection driver is even considering the translateBinary property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 for iSeries uses EBCDIC natively but the Toolbox JDBC driver will automatically attempt to translate EBCDIC to unicode for you.  Since only some fields are not being translated, it is likely those fields are tagged with CCSID 65535 indicating to the Toolbox driver not to translate them.  You can either tag those fields with a CCSID indicating to translate, or use the **translate binary** driver property, which you're attempting to.  The property is not working because you mis-typed it.  According to this [faq](https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/toolbox/faq/jdbc.html#faqB8), it should be `";translate binary=true"` instead of what you've tried.

Comment: @R Rowe Thanks that was the answer.